# Dual boot - Installing ubuntu on pre-installed windows 8... then lost dual boot

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have an acer laptop, aspire M It came with a pre-installed windows 8.

I've made a boot usb key with ubuntu 13.04, created a 4gb swap partition, and an ext3 partition for ubuntu.

Then on the reboot, it only finds ubuntu in the Grub.

I'm no expert. I know my way around the basic stuff, basic understanding but that's it.

Comment: well trying to install Ubuntu after pre-installed windows is not a good idea..

Comment: @Sushantp606 Surprisingly, Ubuntu now has excellent support for dual-booting. Just be sure you know how to troubleshoot simple errors, and it should work like a charm.

Comment: yes i agreed, but it has many issues when you try to do it after pre-installed windows8, yesterday i have seen a thread to explain it . well i will mention it soon.

Answer (score -1):

Luckily, this is an easy problem to fix. Here's what you need to do:

1. Open a Terminal emulator with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `sudo update-grub` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Wait for the command to finish running.
4. Shut down. (Don't restart! You may have to reboot again to get to Windows 8 if you do.)
5. Turn on your computer.

Now, you should see Windows 8 in the GRUB2 boot menu. Have fun with Ubuntu!

Comment: Hello Dillmo!

Thanks for your answer. Ubuntu IS a lot of fun!

Unfortunately, it didn't seem to work properly. 
I did the grub update three times, and when I shut down the computer, ubuntu "stalls" on two little beads out of five.

Any clues? 
Thanks!